# ASP NET Publishing failed with the error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, publish

faced with the problem of publication ASP.NET project: "Publishing failed with the error: One or more errors occurred."
In the log no specifics or more errors. Cntrl + Shift + B is preparing a draft, but publish nothing.

What could be the problem?

[image]

**update**

[image]

I created the project in visual studio 2015, are now working in visual studio, 2017. Can be this the problem?

**fixed**

I went through all the attached javascript library. The draft was published.

Comment: I would start by checking your write / delete permissions to the distination directory / server.

Comment: Try manually deleting the contents of the 'obj' folder

Comment: Sometimes it's because you need to be running VS as Administrator to be able to write to the target directory.

Comment: I work in windows 10, and have never faced a problem of access rights to the directory.

Comment: Have you tried as administrator rights in VS

Comment: I started VS2017 with administrator rights and deleted the contents of the obj folder, it didn't help.

Comment: @al.koval .. Did you change the .Net Framework when you are trying in 2017 ?

Comment: Hello, no. I used the default framework.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck this option: **Delete all existing files prior to publish**, On your settings, then delete directories on your destination directory and try again.